# Can't import file from another directory which imports a file from the same directory (int Python)

Tags: python, import, module, packaging

So my project structure is the following:

```
project/
    src/
        __init__.py
        utils.py
        model.py
    usage.py
```

I now want to import functions from utils.py and a class in model.py into my usage.py. But the model.py itself imports functions from utils.py.

So I am doing the following:

```
# usage.py

from src.model import Model
from src.utils import onehot_to_string
```

But I am getting the error that it couldnt import functions from utils.py into the model.py:

```
File "usage.py", line 11, in <module>
    from src.model import *
  File "/project/src/model.py", line 7, in <module>
    from utils import onehot_to_string
ImportError: cannot import name 'onehot_to_string' from 'utils' (/lib/python3.7/site-packages/utils/__init__.py)
```

I think I am lacking of some basic Python packaging knowledge here. Can someone help me out? :)

Comment: try changing the name of utils `(/lib/python3.7/site-packages/utils/__init__.py)` it is conflicting with system utils package

Comment: Since you mentioned that you are facing issues with utils.py and the model.py could we see the imports for those two files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like python can't find your `utils` file in `model.py`. Then it proceeds to search for `utils` in path and finds it because, for example, someone has installed some library named `utils`. Then, the error occurs because this previously installed `utils` library has no `onehot_to_string` function.

Try to change your `from utils import onehot_to_string` to `from .utils import onehot_to_string` in `model.py` to use relative import.

Comment: Hi thanks it solved my problem, what does the . do?

Comment: It tells Python to use module in current package, in the original question the package is `src` (i.e. import utils from package src). [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time](This SO thread) has great in-depth answers and links to documentation if interested to learn more, but in summary, relative imports are usable within packages

Answer (score 0):

for file/function/variables importing use this sys method

```
import sys
# insert at 1, 0 is for other usage
sys.path.insert(1, '/path/to/application/app/folder')
```